# Windows XP blue screen with Adobe Air browser

Tags: ember.js, air, windows-xp

I tried to open the EmberJS official website using Adobe Air browser in Windows XP3.

The machine crashed right away with blue screen of death. Here is the dump error:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : Mini110415-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 11/4/2015 4:38:38 PM
Bug Check String  : RESOURCE_NOT_OWNED
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000e3
Parameter 1       : 0x8a2ef7f8
Parameter 2       : 0x891f4690
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x00000002
Caused By Driver  : win32k.sys
Caused By Address : win32k.sys+19f4
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : 32-bit
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+22fa3
Stack Address 1   : ntoskrnl.exe+5ea49
Stack Address 2   : win32k.sys+19f4
Stack Address 3   : win32k.sys+157286
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : E:\Mini110415-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 2600
Dump File Size    : 94,208
Dump File Time    : 11/4/2015 4:52:10 PM
==================================================
```

Why would it happen? Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions. This isn't a question.

Comment: As genuine interest. Why in the lords name are you using these archaic technologies?

Answer (score 0):

I spent further time to investigate, and found the root cause is actually from font-awesome! That's why angular js website also crashed the XP machine. I remove this library and my webpage loads now. This question could be resolved. Thanks for the comment :D